# Bounds on the L^1 norm of a discrete Fourier spectrum

Tags: fourier-analysis, inequalities

I am dealing with a function $f$ of the form
\begin{equation}
f(t):=\sum_{k=1}^Na_ke^{\mathrm{i}\phi_k t}
\end{equation}
and I have a promise that 
\begin{equation}
0\leq f(t)\leq C\;\;\;\text{for all}\;\;\;t\in\mathbb{R},
\end{equation}
where $C>0$ is some constant. My question is the following: What bound can I find for
\begin{equation}
\sum_k|a_k|
\end{equation}
in terms of $C$ and $N$?

Edit: The $\phi_k$ are real numbers and I have the additional promise that $f$ is real. The $a_k$ are complex numbers.

Comment: Are the $\phi_i$ and $a_i$ complex, real? Do you know that $f$ only takes real values?

Comment: Thank you. That was not clear from my formulation. I edited the question.

Comment: If all $\phi_i=0$ then all you get is that $0 \le \sum_i a_i \le C$, but that is not enough to get any bound on $\sum_i |a_i|$. Do you know anything else about the $\phi_i$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid trivialities, I will assume the $\phi_k$ are all distinct. Then

$$ \sum_k |a_k|^2 = \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{2R} \int_{-R}^R |f(t)|^2\; dt 
\le C^2$$

so by Cauchy-Schwarz, $$\sum_k |a_k| \le C \sqrt{N}$$

Comment: I suspected nothing better than direct application of Cauchy Schwartz would be possible in general. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, this is best possible: according to Exercise 3.1.6 in Grafakos' book "Classical Fourier Analysis", the function $1/\sqrt{N}\sum_{k=1}^N e^{i k \log k} e^{ikt}$ is uniformly bounded but the $\ell^1$-norm of its Fourier transform is $\sqrt{N}$. (Taking the real part and adding a large enough constant makes the function positive valued, as you request).